# Apache PATH very long with duplicate entries

Tags: apache-2.2, php, freebsd

When showing `phpinfo()` the sheet show that Apache PATH enviroment variable is very very long and with duplicate entries? Why is that? And how to fix?

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Another server of mine only shows

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Both running FreeBSD 8.1, PHP 5.3.6 and Apache 2.2

The one with issues is also running Virtualmin/Webmin.

Answer (score 1):

Quite frankly, this isn't a big deal.  The `PATH` variable is actually set by the shell originally, and there are probably a dozen other scripts in Virtualmin/Webmin that append paths to it, i.e.:

```
PATH=/path1:/path2:$PATH
PATH=/another/path:$PATH
```

It sounds like there's just been several duplicates added, probably from a lot of overlapping sets.  Fortunately, this shouldn't affect much.  Variables are cached (by the shell), and I'm assuming PHP will do the same when it tries to `eval` binaries.

So, unless you're running into issues, its safe to leave it as is.

Comment: I'm having an issue with including a file in PHP, a language file in ZendFramework. The file is allready a whole lot smaller than on another server where the copied website originated. The file included returns an array(), as [documented in example #5](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). But sometimes the `include` just returns `int(1)` as documented if there is nothing returned. If I pull random parts out of the returned array, it works.

Comment: What you're speaking of is not the PATH variable, then.  In PHP, there's something called an [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) that handles this.